# How do I use Virtualbox to create a dev environment accessible outside of my home office?

Tags: windows-7, ssh, ftp, centos, virtualbox

I have created a dev environment of my website... using VirtualBox... and now I need to make it accessible outside of my home office network.  I am using Virtualbox 4.1.18 installed on a Win7 desktop host.  The virtual machine is running CentOS 5.6.  My home office has a static ip.  I am using a Linksys router e4200.  The virtual machine is setup to use a bridged adapter.  My virtual machine can access the web.  My host pc can ping the virtual machine successfully.  Other PC's on my home network can successfully ping my host pc and the virtual machine.  I have given the virtual machine its own static IP on my network as well.

How do I test if others outside my home office network can see this dev server?  Which ip address will point to the dev server in this scenario?

What should I do next so that third party developers can access this server via ftp and/or ssh?

Comment: Any of this helping? http://superuser.com/questions/273385/how-to-access-guest-server-from-the-web http://superuser.com/questions/383156/how-to-make-ubuntu-vm-in-virtualbox-accessible-from-the-internet

Comment: Thanks Oliver but no... none of those links helped.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to your Router and set the **virtual server** to have the static IP; not your virtual host.

Alternatively, you could forward ports using Virtualbox (not sure how easy that is), but it's more work than just giving your CentOS box the static IP. The router doesn't really care that it's a virtual server, because you're using bridged networking.

The IP you would use, afterwards, is the public IP of your home network.

Good luck

Comment: Won't setting the VM to have the static IP cause other machines on his network to lose connectivity?

Comment: I don't think so, judging from my experience with consumer-grade Cisco routers.

Comment: Try forwarding ports such as 80 (HTTP) and 22 (SSH) and others to your VM's private IP address, so only ports you need are passed to the VM.

Comment: I did that.  Using Filezilla I am unable to FTP successfully to the virtual server using the home office IP and port 21 (which is the port I set to forward).

Comment: On the CentOS server, do "service iptables stop" as root to see if it's your firewall blocking it.

Comment: I got "bash: service: command not found" in response

Answer (score 0):

You will need to forward the ports to your virtual machine. If it's set to bridged, it should be sitting on your network just like any other physical machine would. From that point it's a matter of getting your router to direct incoming FTP and SSH traffic to your server using port forwarding.

Comment: When I turn on Port Forwarding, using the common ports (80,21,22), my virtual server loses internet connectivity.  While troubleshooting I performed the following actions: 1. On the virtual server I turned off static ip - still no internet 2. In my physical router I released the DHCP ip reservation - still no internet 3. Disabled the port forwarding - internet access back for virtual server.